# why float:lefted is little bit lower?

Tags: html, css

Here is [my codes](http://jsfiddle.net/24xqX/). I can't solve why `id=right` is little bit lower? How can i solve?

My css codes:

```
#container
{
    width:70%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

body
{
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#708090;
}

#left
{
    float:left;
}

#content
{

}

#right
{
    float:right;
}
```

right div's value is only `float:right`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `<div id="right">` before the `<div id="left">` or before `<div id="content">` and it works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/24xqX/1/

Comment: See @Cristoph's answer with the explanation

Comment: the order does not matter. It needs to be before the unfloated content. see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your floats before unfloated content. So basically, `#left` and `#right` need to be before your `#content` in the markup. In which order `#left` and `#right` are doesn't matter.

Also it is always a good idea to clear the floats of your elements ( e.g. via [pseudo clearfix](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/)).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#left
{
    float:left;
}

#content
{
float:left;
}

#right
{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Although this fixes the problem I find this solution rather bad. I'm against "I just float as much elements as possible" nonsense.

Comment: Downvoting my answer won't change my opinion. But if you got your peace of mind through this action go ahead.

Comment: In fact I am downvoting your answer because you significantly change the behaviour of the markup when a better solution would have solved the problem too.